# Action Item is not displaying on action bar in all other activity except main activity (Android)

Tags: android

This is my menu xml file...

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
          <item android:id="@+id/action"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search_dark"
             yourapp:showAsAction="always" /></menu>
```

here is my java code...

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Did you overide the onCreateOptionsMenu method in all the activities

Comment: Are you using fragments?

Comment: No, i have not used any fragment. Yes, shiv i had overridden onCreateOptionsMenu in all my activities.